# What's the difference between stellen and aufstellen?

Tags: meaning

Hey everybody I've tried to understand for a while what's the difference between stellen and aufstellen but I can't really see the difference, can anybody help me with that?

Comment: Which translations did you find for both words in a dictionary? Yes, they have one common meaning, but the different other translations should give you an idea about the differences...

Comment: *I suggest leave open:* Translators, particularly google translate, give catastrophal results for similar queries. It is not so easy as it seems.

Comment: @peterh Nevertheless, the question can be improved by adding the results of previous research in a dictionary, or example sentences, where these verbs might be interchangeable

Comment: @Marzipanherz It is right.

Answer (score 5):

*Stellen* always requires a directional object (*Wohin?*):

> Peter stellt das Buch in den Schrank.
>
> Peter stellt die Tasse auf den Tisch.

Note, although here the 2nd sentence also has a combination of the words *stellen* and *auf*, this is not to be confused with *aufstellen*, as *auf den Tisch* is the directional object.

*Aufstellen* has different meanings. In the most literal sense, it means to erect something

> Peter stellt die Statue auf.

It can also mean to place something in order. For example, if Peter was to arrange books on the table for a presentation, and the books are standing (i.e. are in upright position)

> Peter **stellt** die Bücher *auf dem Tisch* **auf**.

Here we have a combination of **aufstellen** and a locational object *auf dem Tisch* ("wo"? as opposed to *wohin*?).

I can recommend this online dictionary for a thorough list [dict.cc aufstellen](https://www.dict.cc/?s=aufstellen). Also, you can find more example sentences on [duden.de aufstellen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufstellen)